# Unhandled exception While trying to change a value of a char pointer in C

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on basic pointers program om VISUAL STUDIO 2013:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void try1(char *c);

int main()
{
    int stop;

    char * c = "rotem";

    try2(c);

    printf_s(" %s \n \n ", c);

    scanf_s("%d", &stop);
    return 0;
}

void try2(char *c)
{

    *c = (char)(*c + 1);

}
```

However, i get this messege:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x009F152A in Project32.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x009F5860.
```

What should I do?

Comment: "rotem" is a literal string, it is in read only memory, you cannot modify it

Comment: You can't motify string literals.

Comment: Literal strings like `"rotmem"` are stored in read only section. So you cannot modify them. You should copy them to a buffer you create to manipulate it.

Comment: I get it now.
so ```char c[10] = "rotem";``` should work. thanks!

Comment: Didn't you get a warning? I believe newer compilers would ask for const char *.

Answer (score 0):

`"rotem"` is a literal string, it is in read only memory, you cannot modify it

duplicate it, or use an array because in your case you do not need to increase its size replacing

> ```
> char * c = "rotem";
> ```

by

```
 char c[] = "rotem";
```

Also replace

> ```
> void try1(char *c);
> ```

by

```
void try2(char *c);
```